# changing string with sed, where did it go?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, scripts

```
$ cat test-paths.txt 
test/sub2/configuration.php
test/sub3/configuration.php
test/configuration.php
test/sub1/configuration.php

$ cat find-host-test 
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat test-paths.txt`
 do 
  echo $i
  grep "public \$host = '127.0.0.1';" $i
  #echo $?
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
    echo "there's config file"
    sed $i 's/$host = 127.0.0.1/$host = localhost/' 
    echo "changed to"
    grep "public \$host =" $i
  fi
 done
```

running `find-host-test` resulted in

```
$ bash find-host-test 
test/sub2/configuration.php
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
there's config file
sed: can't find label for jump to `est/sub2/configuration.php'
changed to
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
test/sub3/configuration.php
test/configuration.php
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
there's config file
sed: can't find label for jump to `est/configuration.php'
changed to
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
test/sub1/configuration.php
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
there's config file
sed: can't find label for jump to `est/sub1/configuration.php'
changed to
    public $host = '127.0.0.1';
```

Why the disappereance of "t" of test folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sed` invokation is wrong.

```
sed 's/$host = 127.0.0.1/$host = localhost/' "$i"
```

See the manual page of `sed`:

```
sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]
```

The inputfile is the last argument, not hte first.

**Interessting sidenote**: `t` in `sed` is called a label. After `t` the name of the label follows. In your case it's the input filename without the leading `t`. `sed` therefore tries to jump to a label called `est/sub2/configuration.php`, which `sed` cannot find anywhere. The second expression `s///g` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your `sed` is not working was already given by chaos's good answer.

Let me go a bit step further to indicate another way to loop through your file, since you are using some unnecessary steps:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "$file"
    if grep -q "public \$host = '127.0.0.1';" "$file"; then
        echo "there's config file"
        sed 's/$host = 127.0.0.1/$host = localhost/' "$file"
        echo "changed to"
        grep "public \$host =" "$file"
    fi
done < "test-paths.txt"
```

Differences:

- You are using `for i in $(cat test-paths.txt)` (well, with backticks, but I don't know how to quote them). This is ok, but it is better to use a beautiful `while` loop doing `while read line; do ... done < file`. This way you read one line at a time. See a broader discussion about the topic in [To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read' loop.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2013)
- Also, using backticks is deprecated. It is better to use `$()`, since it is possible to nest them. (In fact, we already observed this is even bad when posting an answer here :) )
- There is no need to `grep "something"` and then check the `$?` status. You can directly use `grep -q` for this.
- Some of these suggestions can be also found by pasting your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: `$file` should also be enclosed in double quotes when it's used as an argument, to avoid word-splitting and pathname expansion occuring on the result. E.g. `grep -q "public \$host = '127\.0\.0\.1';" "$file"`

Comment: Fair enough, I added safety double quotes all around. Thanks, @geirha